xAct Tensor Reduction
I am just starting out with using xAct (including Invar, xTras, xPert, etc. to expect to see me often) and I have a question on further reducing tensors more. Here is the code I have (I have loaded in xTensor and xTras):
DefManifold[M, dim, IndexRange[a, l]]
DefMetricPerturbation /. Options@DefMetric
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g", 

CurvatureRelations -> True]
DefTensor[\[Phi][], M]
DefConstantSymbol[\[Kappa]];
DefConstantSymbol[\[Alpha]];
DefConstantSymbol[\[Beta]];

L3 = \[Kappa]*RicciScalarCD[] + \[Alpha]/4*\[Phi][]*(1/2*epsilonmetric[c, d, e, f] RiemannCD[a, -b, -e, -f] RiemannCD[b, -a, -c, -d]) - \[Beta]/2 CD[-a][\[Phi][]] CD[a][\[Phi][]]

I evaluated the Lagrangian with the following code:
Collect[FullSimplification[][VarL[metric[-a, -b], CD][L3] // ToCanonical], {\[Kappa], \[Alpha], \[Beta]}]

Here is what I find (warning, it is a bit lengthy but apparently correct):
\[Kappa] (- RicciCD[a, b] + 1/2  metric[a, b]  RicciScalarCD[]) + 
\[Beta]  (1/2 (CD[a][\[Phi][]]) (CD[b][\[Phi][]]) - 1/4  metric[a, b]  (CD[-c][\[Phi][]])  (CD[c][\[Phi][]])) +
\[Alpha] (1/4  epsilonmetric[-d, -e, -f, -g]   RiemannCD[a, c, d, e] RiemannCD[b, -c, f, g]  \[Phi][] - 1/8  epsilonmetric[b, -c, -f, -g]   RiemannCD[a, c, d, e]   RiemannCD[-d, -e, f, g]  \[Phi][] - 1/8  epsilonmetric[a, -c, -f, -g]   RiemannCD[b, c, d, e]   RiemannCD[-d, -e, f, g]  \[Phi][] + 1/4  epsilonmetric[b, -d, -e, -f]   RiemannCD[a, -c, e, f]  (CD[d][CD[c][\[Phi][]]]) + 1/4  epsilonmetric[a, -d, -e, -f]   RiemannCD[b, -c, e, f]  (CD[d][CD[c][\[Phi][]]]) + 1/2  epsilonmetric[b, -c, -d, -e]  (CD[c][\[Phi][]]) (CD[e][RicciCD[a, d]]) + 1/2  epsilonmetric[a, -c, -d, -e]  (CD[c][\[Phi][]]) (CD[e][RicciCD[b, d]]) + 1/2  epsilonmetric[b, -c, -d, -e]  \[Phi][] (CD[e][CD[d][RicciCD[a, c]]]) + 1/2  epsilonmetric[a, -c, -d, -e]  \[Phi][] (CD[e][CD[d][RicciCD[b, c]]]) + 1/4  epsilonmetric[b, -d, -e, -f]  (CD[c][\[Phi][]]) (CD[f][RiemannCD[a, -c, d, e]]) + 1/4  epsilonmetric[a, -d, -e, -f]  (CD[c][\[Phi][]]) (CD[f][RiemannCD[b, -c, d, e]]))

The amazing thing however is that the Einstein term (with the $\kappa$) and the energy-momentum tensor of the scalar field $\phi$ (the $\beta$-term) match exactly to the results in: Chern-Simons Modified General Relativity (equations 15-18)!
But, as you can see, sorting the Levi-Civita terms attached to the Riemann tensors in the final $\alpha$-term do not simplify easily down to what is in the paper. I can eyeball it (using the Riemann Bianchi identity and the symmetries of the Riemann tensor and the Levi Civita tensor), but I would like to be able to do this within Mathematica.
Thus, my question is, how can I reduce those terms that should cancel in the $\alpha$-term to find an exact match with equation 16 in the paper I linked above? Do I have to make a rule (via "MakeRule") or is there an add-on file that Invar can use?
